# Deshabilitar inputs al seleccionar opciones de un SELECT

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente SELECT que esta conectada con una base de datos. Ademas, al seleccionar un dato de la lista del SELECT, me muestra en los respectivos INPUT los datos correspondiente de los campos asociados con la selección hecha en el SELECT.

Lo que deseo es que al seleccionar cualquier dato de la lista del SELECT, me deshabilite ciertos INPUT. Hasta ahora he podido deshabilitar los INPUTS que deseo solo cuando clickeo en una opción del SELECT y no agrego el código para que me muestren los datos en los INPUT. Pero cuando incluyo el código para que si se muestren en los INPUT los datos correspondientes a la selección que se haga en el SELECT , éstos no se deshabilitan.

En conclusión, quiero que al seleccionar cualquier opción de la lista del SELECT, se me deshabiliten ciertos INPUTS, manteniendo los datos correspondientes en los INPUT de acuerdo a la selección que se haga en el SELECT.

**Código que no deshabilita los INPUT, cuando pongo el codigo para que muestre los datos en el INPUT segun seleccion en el SELECT**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>

</head>


<body>
<form>

 <div align="center">   

  <select id="colaboradores" onchange="deshabilitar(this)">

              <script type="text/javascript">
              document.getElementById('colaboradores').onchange = function() {
               
                var mOption = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
               
                var mData = mOption.dataset;
                
                var elCodigo = document.getElementById('codigo');
               
                var elDni = document.getElementById('dni');
                
                 elCodigo.value = this.value;
               
                elDni.value = mData.dni;
              };


               function deshabilitar(obj) {
                      var hab;
                      
                      frm=obj.form;
                      num=obj.selectedIndex;

                       if (num) hab=true;
                       frm.codigo.disabled=hab;
                      frm.dni.disabled=hab;
                      
                    }

                                    
              </script>



        <option value="0" data-dni="" selected disabled>--Seleccione colaborador--</option>
          <?php          

                  $query = $conn -> query ("SELECT * FROM colaborador");
                  while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
                      $data="data-dni=\"$row[dni]\""; 
                      $value="value=\"$row[codigo]\"";                      
                      echo "<option $value $data>$row[nombre]</option>";          
                  }
          ?>
    </select>
<hr />
  
    <input id="codigo" type="text" placeholder="codigo" />

    <input id="dni" type="text" placeholder="DNI" />
      
</div>


</form>


</body>
</html>
```

**Código que si dehabilita los INPUT, sin poner el codigo para que muestre los datos en el INPUT segun selección en el SELECT**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>

</head>


<body>
<form>

 <div align="center">   

  <select id="colaboradores" onchange="deshabilitar(this)">

              <script type="text/javascript">
              
               function deshabilitar(obj) {
                      var hab;
                      
                      frm=obj.form;
                      num=obj.selectedIndex;

                       if (num) hab=true;
                       frm.codigo.disabled=hab;
                      frm.dni.disabled=hab;
                      
                    }

                                    
              </script>



        <option value="0" data-dni="" selected disabled>--Seleccione colaborador--</option>
          <?php          

                  $query = $conn -> query ("SELECT * FROM colaborador");
                  while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
                      $data="data-dni=\"$row[dni]\""; 
                      $value="value=\"$row[codigo]\"";                      
                      echo "<option $value $data>$row[nombre]</option>";          
                  }
          ?>
    </select>
<hr />
  
    <input id="codigo" type="text" placeholder="codigo" />

    <input id="dni" type="text" placeholder="DNI" />
      
</div>


</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sube el codigo HTML, que te genera el php, asi nosotros lo podemos probar. Ademas suve el javascript completo, con el error, que nos dices, asi es mas facil probar todo y ver en que falla

Comment: Todo eso que he puesto es el código completo HTML y Javascript. El conflicto se da al colocar ese código Javascript del primer parrafo, osea, todo el códigoque está dentro de esta función: **document.getElementById('colaboradores').onchange = function()**

Comment: Quiero que al seleccionar cualquier opción de la lista del SELECT, se me deshabiliten ciertos INPUTS, manteniendo los datos correspondientes en los INPUT de acuerdo a la selección que se haga en el SELECT.

Comment: Listo aunque tal vez deverias de invertir el orden de las funciones, primer deverias ejecutar el cargarDatos, y despues el deshabilitar, pero en fin, creo que ya quedo, checalo y me avisas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**El problema es que, primero ligabas el onChange a  deshabilitar, y después lo volvías a ligarla a otra función, obvio el onchage quedaba ligada solo a la última función, lo que hago es que la función deshabilitar, mande llamar la otra función que también quiere ejecutar en onchange, así se ejecutan las dos**

```js
function cargarDatos(obj) {
      
 var mOption = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex];
   
 var mData = mOption.dataset;
 
 var elCodigo = document.getElementById('codigo');
   
 var elDni = document.getElementById('dni');
 
  elCodigo.value = obj.value;
   
 elDni.value = mData.dni;
}

function deshabilitar(obj) {
   var hab;
   
   frm=obj.form;
   num=obj.selectedIndex;

  if (num) hab=true;
   frm.codigo.disabled=hab;
   frm.dni.disabled=hab;
    
    cargarDatos(obj);
   
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>

</head>


<body>
<form>

 <div align="center">   

  <select id="colaboradores" onchange="deshabilitar(this)">

              



        <option value="0" data-dni="" selected disabled>--Seleccione colaborador--</option>
          <?php          

                  $query = $conn -> query ("SELECT * FROM colaborador");
                  while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
                      $data="data-dni=\"$row[dni]\""; 
                      $value="value=\"$row[codigo]\"";                      
                      echo "<option $value $data>$row[nombre]</option>";          
                  }
          ?>
    </select>
<hr />
  
    <input id="codigo" type="text" placeholder="codigo" />

    <input id="dni" type="text" placeholder="DNI" />
      
</div>


</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Y la línea de código **document.getElementById('colaboradores').onchange = function()** ? Ya no debería ponerlo? Es que eso servía para mostrar los datos de los campos de mi tabla en mi base de datos en los INPUTS según la seleccion que se hacia en el SELECT.

Comment: No ya no. Es que si pones esa linea esta sobreescriviendo el onChange del select, si te fijas en la funcion deshabilitar, se manda llamar  "cargarDatos", esa funcion hara lo que hacia  document.getElementById('colaboradores').onchange asi que ya no la necesitas

Comment: La funcion  cargarDatos(obj) esta remplazando la funcion de la  linea  document.getElementById('colaboradores').onchange, elimina toda esa funcion y remplazala por la de cargarDatos

Comment: prueba el codigo y me comentas, creo que si funciona, porque carga los datos

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo probé y si me sirvió. Adicional a eso, al deshabilitar los inputs con datos dentro de él, es posible volver a registrar con los inputs deshabilitados?

Comment: A que te refieres con volver a registrar?

Comment: Si te refieres a cambiar los valores de los input (si se pueden), pero los input que estan deshabilitados no se mandan( osea que no llegan en el array de POST)

Comment: Tampoco se mandan los inputs que no tienen al campo name

Comment: Leí que si se podia mandar datos del input deshabilitado, algo de crear un INPUT oculto o algo así vi por ahi, no se que tan cierto sea eso posible...?

Comment: Has la práctica tú, yo la hice para verificar , Y los input deshabilitados no se crean en $_POST de php. Los input tipo hidden y ocultos esos si funcionan. Prueba y me comentas

Comment: Ya veo... He revisado información y encontré un atributo que deja a los INPUTs sin poder editar, los deja solo de lectura, pero si se pueden enviar, me refiero al READONLY. Creo que ese atributo es el que mas se adecua a mi proyecto que vengo realizando, y en ese caso, como haría para poder implementarlo en la pregunta de este post? Osea, hay alguna manera de que en vez de poner DISABLED, se pueda reemplazar con READONLY para poder enviar los datos por medio del metodo POST? Y si ese fuera el caso, como lo tendría que poner en el código que esta en la pregunta de este tema?

Comment: es similar al disabled, intenta cambiar por estas dos lineas

Comment: frm.codigo.readOnly=hab;
frm.dni.readOnly=hab;